# How to remove header, new line character and ""

Tags: sql, oracle11g, ansi-sql

I have query in oracle which gives output as

```
"S.ACQUIRER||'|'||SUBSTR(S.ACQ_COUNTRY,1,4)||'|'||SUBSTR(S.ACQ_CURRENCY_CODE,1,5)||'|'||S.PAN||'|'||SUBSTR(S.ACCTNUM,1,18)||'|'||SU\
BSTR(I.E_NAME,1,35)||'|'||S.LOCAL_DATE||'|'||S.LOCAL_TIME||'|'||DECODE(S.PCODE,0,'POSTRANSACTIONFROMDEFAULTACCOUNT',1000,'POS"
"9000000007|840|840|5048349120900000008|504834000000006028|Ecustomer name                     |03-JAN-14|115744|Cash Withdrawl from\
Savings Account |10|Approved |2000061|ATM Test Terminal        Bang      |123400000123456          |01001101"
"9000000007|840|840|5048349120900000008|504834000000006028|Ecustomer name                     |03-JAN-14|115744|Cash Withdrawl from\
Savings Account |10|10|4000061|ATM Test Terminal        Bang      |123450000000456          |01001101"
```

How ever expected output is

```
9000000007|840|840|5048349120900000008|504834000000006028|Ecustomer name                     |03-JAN-14|115744|Cash Withdrawl from Savings Account |10|Approved |2000061|ATM Test Terminal        Bang      |123400000123456          |01001101

9000000007|840|840|5048349120900000008|504834000000006028|Ecustomer name                     |03-JAN-14|115744|Cash Withdrawl from Savings Account |10|10|4000061|ATM Test Terminal        Bang      |123450000000456          |01001101
```

What I expected was that:

1. There should no header
2. There should no "" at start each line and end as well
3. New line character "\" should not present

I have tried to remove header with below commands but no success

set HEADING OFF

set pagesize 0

How can I achieve the output without the header, `"` and `\` ?

Comment: also where is the query

Answer (score 1):

`SET HEADDING OFF` does not exists in `Oracle` , please use

```
SET HEADING OFF
```